# WCF bindings, basicHttpBinding versus wsHttpBnding

Tags: wcf, binding

My WCF never worked with wsbinding, but when I switched to basic it worked fine.

What do I have to do to make wsbinding work?

**Update**

when I say it didn't work, I mean the client was never able to consume the services endpoints.

**Do I have to add a username/password somewhere?**

Comment: What was the error message? Can you provide more inputs?

Comment: It's not a matter of username/password (assuming you configured it correctly).  Can you give us more information about the client, is it a Silverlight app?  Can Visual Studio generate a Service Reference when wsBinding is used?

Answer (score 1):

First, are you using Visual Studio 2005 or 2008?  Next if you are using VS2005 did you install the .NET 3.0 CTP tools for WCF/WF that was released in 2006?  I ask these questions because I wanted to know how you setup your proxy class in the client.  Did you right click and do "add service reference" or "add web reference"

Also, does your WCF config file look similar to the below?  This shows a dual setup, both Basic and WsHttp Bindings.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttp">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NorthwindBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="NorthwindBehavior" name="SampleApplicationWCF.Library.SupplierService">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp" name="wsHttpSupplierService" contract="SampleApplicationWCF.Library.ISupplierService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```